# Elastic Search make a number field score ultimate relevancy

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field named **likes**. When I search for a name I want the doc which has highest likes to come at the top. But it doesn't.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Lon"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "likes": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sorting on two fields, `"_score"` and `"likes"`. This will sort by `"_score"` and if there is a tie (the scores are the same between two results) then it will use `"likes"` to sort between the records that have the same `"_score"`. From your question it sounds like you only want to sort on `"likes"` and `"_score"` is not as relevant. So modify your query to sort just by `"likes"`.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "Lon"
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        { "likes" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ]
}
```

Comment: _score can be second maybe. I will change the order then.